# Prevent page reload after form submit / node (no ajax available)

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, node.js, formidable

Good day, I have a form for sending fields **and file** to node.js server. On server the data parsed by **Formidable**. Everything is working good, but after form submitted it loads a page with a response. 
Does anyone know either the way to send the data with standard form mechanisms **and** not reload page (jQuery ajax method with serialize will not work because of **file in form**) either write such response on server so it will not trigger page reload.
Form:

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="eventForm">
<label>Date</label>
<input type="text" name="date"/>
<label>Image</label>
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="picture" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Server side:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    // save file code goes here 
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        //response code goes here
        res.send('done');
    });
});
```

Any better ways to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Please see if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery) and its answers helps you. To be clear, the answers in it are about solving it with Javascript or even JQuery.

Comment: have a look at http://blog.w3villa.com/programming/upload-image-without-submitting-form-works-on-all-browsers/

Comment: what did you do? I see you accept the answer but I dont know if it works for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to both of people who answered in comments to my question!
Both of their solutions are working and here they are:

1) Easiest: add invisible iframe after the form and specify it as a target of a form:

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="eventForm" target="uploader_iframe">
//....
</form>
<iframe id="uploader_iframe" name="uploader_iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

2) Correct: actually it is not that hard to use AJAX to send the same data, you just need to specify some parameters to make it work right. Here is a code:

```
$('#eventForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/upload',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Thank you both commentators! Use their links to find more about it!